# Why did Furlow copy Crichton's module? And what exactly did she copy?

Tags: spaceship, farscape, wormhole

In episode 1x11 "Till the Blood Runs Clear", Crichton meets Furlow, who comes to know the specifications of his module. In episode 1x16 "A Human Reaction", Crichton meets the Ancients, who give him the wormhole knowledge. But Furlow herself is not seen in that episode, or in fact seen again at all until episode 3x14 "Infinite Possibilities Part 1: Daedalus Demands", where she is seen to have copied Crichton's module and used the knowledge in wormhole experiments.

The Ancients then assume that Crichton has fed information to Furlow and the Charrids, and question whether they were right to trust him. However, clearly they are wrong to even think that, as Furlow never met John between when he was in contact with the Ancients and when she copied his module. Right?

So since Furlow didn't have any specific technical data from Crichton's secret wormhole knowledge in her analysis of Crichton's module, why did she try to copy his module and then use the copy in wormhole experiments? And since Crichton's module couldn't possibly have had any modifications relating to his wormhole knowledge at the time that Furlow analysed it (as he hadn't even received the wormhole knowledge then), what exactly did Furlow copy that gave her something useful for the wormhole experiments?

I think it's stated somewhere that Furlow fitted the copy with a component (checking online, it seems it's called a "phase stabilizer") to allow it to pass through wormholes. This doesn't seem to make much sense either, because Crichton passed through a wormhole in his unmodified module in the very first episode of the show. But either way, this seems to suggest that there wasn't anything intrinsic about the module which allowed it to travel through wormholes, so I'm not sure what was worth copying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Crichton's module is the only craft known to have conveyed a life form through a wormhole intact. Regardless of whether Crichton had wormhole knowledge when he met Furlow, this made the module an object of potential interest.

While you are correct in stating that there may have been nothing intrinsic to the module which contributed to its successful wormhole journey, using a copy of the module to attempt to reproduce wormhole travel eliminates one set of variables from the experiment.

Presumably, the first step in attaining controlled wormhole travel would be recreating Crichton's experience reliably. From there, experiments could be run, changing various parameters of the flight to collect data and learn the "rules" of wormhole travel. These experiments may yield the knowledge that the module was irrelevant; however, until the initial flight is duplicated, using any other craft will complicate matters. Each failure would raise the question, "Is the problem inherent to the craft we are using?" Even if a successful flight is made, any subsequent failure may raise the same question.

Comment: Add to that the fact that Peacekeepers who fly through wormholes in Prowlers come back as Cockpit-o-Soup, and you realize that you'd run out of test pilots pretty quick without a reliable starting point. Furlow was smarter than even Scorpius in this regard. Scorpius should have been trying to get his hands on Farscape One!

Comment: @JohnSensebe - Luckily, the fact that the peacekeeper fleet is comprised of effective slaves means that there's no shortage of test-pilots. You just keep chucking them in until something works...

Comment: Yeah, but they could have saved a lot of time drying out Prowlers.